# module has no Attribute in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

i check everything but i still can't figure out the problem. this is the error that i get "AttributeError: module 'users.views' has no attribute 'CustomerSignUp'  "

urls.py

```
    path('customer/register/', views.CustomerSignUp.as_view(), name='customer_homepage'),
    path('merchant/signup/',views.MerchantSignUpView.as_view(), name='merchant_signup'),
```

views.py

```
class CustomerSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = CustomerSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'customer'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('catalog:index')
```

thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

It's called `CustomerSignUpView` not `CustomerSignUp`.